# How to prepare a dataset for speech recognition

Tags: speech-recognition, recurrent-neural-network, unsupervised-learning

I need to train a Bidirectional LSTM model to recognize discrete speech (individual numbers from 0 to 9) I have recorded speech from 100 speakers. What should I do next? (Suppose I am splitting them into individual .wav files containing one number per file) I will be using mfcc as features for the network.

Further, I would like to know the difference in the dataset if I am going to use a library that support CTC (Connectionist Temporal Classification)

Comment: Hi. Is your model open-source so I can check it out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the answer/guidance provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34661818/building-speech-dataset-for-lstm-binary-classification)

Depending on what library you are using to create your LSTM(pybrain, theano, keras), you can look through their documentation.

I would recommend using Theano(Binary LSTM [link](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lstm.html)) or Keras([Tutorial)](http://danielhnyk.cz/predicting-sequences-vectors-keras-using-rnn-lstm/) for this because they are fairly simple to understand and are well documented.

hope this helps.