# How to train an lstm for speech recognition

Tags: tensorflow, speech-recognition, keras, speech-to-text, lstm

I'm trying to train lstm model for speech recognition but don't know what training data and target data to use. I'm using the [LibriSpeech dataset](http://www.openslr.org/12/) and it contains both audio files and their transcripts. At this point, I know the target data will be the transcript text vectorized. As for the training data, I was thinking of using the frequencies and time from each audio file (or MFCC features). If that is the correct way to approach the problem, the training data/audio will be multiple arrays, how would I input those array into my lstm model? Will I have to vectorize them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To prepare the speech dataset for feeding into the LSTM model, you can see this post - [Building Speech Dataset for LSTM binary classification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34661818/building-speech-dataset-for-lstm-binary-classification) and also the segment [Data Preparation](http://danielhnyk.cz/predicting-sequences-vectors-keras-using-rnn-lstm/#datapreparation).

As a good example, you can see this post - http://danielhnyk.cz/predicting-sequences-vectors-keras-using-rnn-lstm/. This post talks about **how to predict sequence of vectors in Keras using RNN - LSTM**.

I believe you will find this post (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/192014/how-to-implement-a-lstm-based-classifier-to-classify-speech-files-using-keras) very helpful too.

Comment: @user562 Can you please share the approach or code source for ASR model. I have been working for my college project and didn't got the much information on it.